# javascript - script from remote server slow load

Tags: javascript, html

In my site header I have a script tag which loads a secure certificate badge.
This badge is loaded from the certificate authority server and is sometimes slow to load.
This also slows down the loading of the rest of the site, since it is waiting for the badge to finish loading.

Is there any way to tell the rendering browser to continue loading other elements and not wait for the script to load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do "lazy" loading of scripts using something like [load.js](https://github.com/chriso/load.js) - prevent the scripts from blocking.

Answer (score 1):

Put the script tag right before the

```
</body>
```

tag.  That way it will be loaded last and everything else can load first.

It's actually best practice to always put javascript in the footer instead the header for exactly this reason.  For example, if you've ever implemented Google Analytics, they tell you to do this.

Here is a blog post about this from Yahoo! developers:  http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

Comment: who knows, I got one too - in fact, let me rectify that, because your answer didn't deserve a down-vote

Comment: Valid point, but when I said header, I didn't mean the HTML header, just the header of the page itself (Where the logo is, etc.)